# Excel Date Formatting is Being Changed from Date to General on Moblie Preview

Tags: excel

So we have a weekly report that gets sent out. In the report there are dates assigned to production numbers and for some reason when previewed from a mobile device the dates are changed to integers. 43028 is October 20, 2017. I have no idea where this number is coming from, because this goes back to December 30, 1899. I have no idea why it's switching into this form and only on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is how excel handles dates. The integer represents a count from a set date (you can enter 0 into a cell and format it as a date to find the starting date). Every +1 represents the next day from that starting point. Your decimals represent hours (.5 = half day).

You can try a helper column and set it equal to your date using `=TEXT(A2,"m/dd/yyyy")` where A2 is your current date. Date format can be adjusted to taste.

Comment: The irony is that I typed that response up on my phone (those are default quotes on iPhone) and the issue is related to mobile lulz. Good eye